# Css transition animation not working with .appendChild

Tags: css, transform, translate3d

I'm making a game with javascript and css and so on.
Animation of character is slow in some mobile browsers. Now it is working with a callback.

User request tile, server looks if tile is free, server send packet to move avatar.

so user is going to walk to that tile, server sends tile where to go .

```
var movecallback = avatars.moved(id);
movelayer('ava_'+id, ava_x, ava_y, 25, 20, 1, movecallback);
```

before something was done with `movecallback` function but I remove that and make use CSS3 transform because that is smoother.

see this

```
$("ava_"+id).style.transform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';
                $("ava_"+id).style.OTransform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';          // Opera
                $("ava_"+id).style.msTransform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';         // IE 9
                $("ava_"+id).style.MozTransform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';        // Firefox
                $("ava_"+id).style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';
```

And on css I have this:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
```

this is working very well, but not in the game, in the game the user is going to another div with this function `$("tile"+tile).appendChild($("ava_"+id));`

so the css transition is removed when you append div to another? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a side effect of a browser optimization.
You can use a very short timeout to avoid it, like [here](http://codepen.io/tkrugg/pen/sABcx).

So for your case, try something like:

```
$("tile"+tile).appendChild($("ava_"+id));
setTimeout(function(){       
   $("ava_"+id).style.transform = 'translate3d('+ava_x+'px, '+ava_y+'px,0)';
}, 1);
```

Comment: Looks like this worked, I still got a lot of work but it's nice!! Thanks!!