# How to smoothly add dynamically created element to the DOM using CSS3 only?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

My need is quite straightforward, yet I could not find a proper solution.

I create elements and add them to the DOM as a list of item, each new element is added before the old ones. I would like the new elements to be added "smoothly". The `height` of each elements is dynamic, so has to be the CSS rules.

I think I have to use CSS `animations` and `keyframes`, from what I read I can't use `transitions` because sometimes [it is not rendered by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295804/2291710). I don't want to use Javascript, so I prefer to avoid solution with `setTimeout()` or `jQuery`. I'm sure this can be correctly done using modern CSS, but I still have to found the proper way to do so.

I have the begin of a solution (see below), **but** there is still `max-height: 1000px` hardcoded in the CSS, and I would like to avoid that, but I do not know how to because replacing it with `auto` or `unset` breaks the animation (see GIFs at the end of the post).

How would you implement a elegant transition for adding new elements to the DOM like this (not necessarily using the code I provided)?

---

[**Try the code on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qk9gjrhd/3/)

```js
    function addElement() {
        let dynamicHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30) + 100;
        let newElem = `<div class='elem' style='height: ${dynamicHeight}px'></div>`;
        let elements = document.getElementById("elements");
        elements.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", newElem);
    }

    let button = document.getElementById("button")
    button.addEventListener("click", addElement);
```

```css
    .elem {
      background-color: blue;
      margin: 5px;
      animation-duration:0.5s;
      animation-name: slidein;
    }
    
    
    @keyframes slidein {
      from {
        max-height: 0px;
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    
      to {
        max-height: 1000px;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <button id="button">Add element</button>
    <div id="elements"></div>
```

---

**With hardcoded max-height (looks nice):**
[image: With hardcoded max-height]

**With unset max-height (looks clumsy):**
[image: With unset max-height]

Comment: have you tried using height: auto; ?

Comment: @ManuelBlanco Yes, I tried with `auto`, `unset` and `100%` and it was "clumsy" for all of them.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What do you mean by "reduce the time of the second animation"? How can I do this? The "clumsy" effect comes from the fact that the old element "jump down" instead of moving smoothly to the bottom.

Comment: @Delgan Ah! I see. Well you either use `max-height` or javascript, otherwise it is not possible: you can't animate or transition from numeric to non numeric values and vice versa.

Comment: I was always under the impression that using `max-height` for sliding element can be overestimated because it'll just goes to it's computed height. If the sliding is linear then there would be an abruptness but an easing can smooth out the jerkiness of an overestimated `max-height` maybe (not tested)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are defining a fixed height the solution is to animate the height from 0px to the fixed value. The trick here is to rely on CSS variable to be able to have a dynamic animation of the elements depending on their height:

```js
function addElement() {
  let dynamicHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100) + 40;
  let newElem = `<div class='elem' style='--h: ${dynamicHeight}px'></div>`;
  let elements = document.getElementById("elements");
  elements.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", newElem);
}

let button = document.getElementById("button")
button.addEventListener("click", addElement);
```

```css
.elem {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: slidein 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    height: 0px;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    height:var(--h); /*This will change for each element */
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add element</button>
<div id="elements"></div>
```

Comment: I did not know of `var()`, thanks! Unfortunately, my real use case is with elements which does not have fixed height, those are just "block" elements with content of variable length.

Comment: @Delgan, ok let me think about another way ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! By the way, if you manage to make any "smooth" transition, I will probably be ok with that, even if there is no scale transformation or something else. It's a bit vague, but as long as adding new elements looks "nice" with old ones being "slided down", I will be happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet fully supported, but [View Traansitions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API) is what you'll need.